# CSS Positioning of an element

Tags: html, css

I am building a chat component in my app.

I have the following:

[image]

I would like to position the tick to the right of the time, and make the tick blue. Much like WhatsApp does it.

Any CSS advise appreciated.

Thank you

**html**

```
    <span class="time-tick">
    <span class="message-timestamp">{{message.createdAt | amDateFormat: 'h:mm a'}}</span>
    <div *ngIf="message.readByReceiver && senderId == message.senderId">
      <span class="checkmark">
          <div class="checkmark_stem"></div>
          <div class="checkmark_kick"></div>
      </span>
    </div>
    </span>
```

**css**

```
.messages-page-navbar {
  .chat-picture {
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    float: left;
  }

  .chat-title {
    line-height: 50px;
    float: left;
  }
}

.messages-page-content {
  > scroll-content {
    padding: 0;
  }

  .messages {
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(/assets/chat-background.jpg);
    background-color: #E0DAD6;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }

  .message-wrapper {
    margin-bottom: 9px;

    &::after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }
  }

  .message {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 236px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);

    &.message-mine {
      float: right;
      background-color: #DCF8C6;

      &::before {
        right: -11px;
        background-image: url(/assets/message-mine.png)
      }
    }

    &.message-other {
      float: left;
      background-color: #FFF;

      &::before {
        left: -11px;
        background-image: url(/assets/message-other.png)
      }
    }

    &.message-other::before, &.message-mine::before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 3px;
      width: 12px;
      height: 19px;
      background-position: 50% 50%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: contain;
    }

    .message-content {
      padding: 5px 7px;
      word-wrap: break-word;

      &::after {
        content: " \00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0";
        display: inline;
      }
    }

    .message-timestamp {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 2px;
      right: 7px;
      font-size: 12px;
      color: gray;
    }
  }
}

.message-datetime {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: grey;
}

.messages-page-footer {
  padding-right: 0;

  .message-editor {
    margin-left: 2px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }

  .message-editor-button {
    background: color($colors, whatsapp);
    box-shadow: none;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 17px;
    margin: auto;
  }
}

.checkmark {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 22px;
    height:22px;
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.checkmark_stem {
    position: absolute;
    width:3px;
    height:9px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    left:11px;
    top:6px;
}

.checkmark_kick {
    position: absolute;
    width:3px;
    height:3px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    left:8px;
    top:12px;
}

.time-tick {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: can u upload snippet code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under `message-timestamp` in your CSS, increase the `right` value from `7px` up to about `15px`.

Then under `.checkmark`, add the following:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 2px;
right: 7px;
```

Comment: Thank you, that was quick! And you solved my problem.

Comment: @Richard Please mark it as the correct answer if you are satisfied.